# postgresql how to run explain analyze on foreach loop

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, sql-execution-plan, explain

I am trying run  `'explain analyze'` the foreach loop in postgresql, but didn't find suitable example in postgres doc. Can anyone help me here.

Here is the example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xyz() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $xyz$
DECLARE
        idList integer[];

        aa integer;
        bb bigint;
        cc integer;
        dd smallint;

BEGIN
        IF NEW.severity = 7
        THEN     
             idList := array(select someid from sometable where someid like NEW.someid);

        END IF;
             FOREACH Id in ARRAY alarmIdList LOOP
                 select a, b, c, d
                        into aa, bb, cc , dd
                 from SomeActivetable where someid = Id;

                 insert into SomeTable2(ba, bb, bc, bd)
                     values(aa, bb, 6, dd);
             END LOOP;

        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$xyz$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks,
Gourav

Comment: please share a plpgsql you have

Comment: You can not run `explain`on a PL/pgSQL statement. That only works with [SQL statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)

Comment: GIven an example, if i want to analyze the whole function. What is the way?

Comment: You don't need a `foreach` loop or an intermediate variable to hold the `idlist`, you can do that with a single `insert ... select ...` statement: http://dpaste.com/0H9F015 but `where someid like new.someid` makes no sense whatsoever. `LIKE` is for string values, not for integer values.

Comment: sure that i can do, but right now i m interested to analyze for each loop or a function.

Comment: You could try [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = true`, but I haven't tested it myself so don't know if it will do what you need.

Comment: Why do you want to analyze a function that is known to be slow and where a much more efficient solution is easy to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a little bit weird way how to do it. See "proof of concept" below - adjust it to your needs...

```
do $$
declare
    _idlist int[] := '{10,20,30}';
    i int;
    _q text;
    _t text;
begin
    foreach i in array _idlist loop
        _q := 'explain analyze select '||i;
        raise notice 'query: %', _q;
        for _t in execute _q loop
            raise notice '%', _t;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Will give you output in "messages" window of pgAdmin (or STDERR on command line) like this:

```
NOTICE:  query: explain analyze select 10
NOTICE:  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
NOTICE:  Planning time: 0.003 ms
NOTICE:  Execution time: 0.012 ms
NOTICE:  query: explain analyze select 20
NOTICE:  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
NOTICE:  Planning time: 0.004 ms
NOTICE:  Execution time: 0.004 ms
NOTICE:  query: explain analyze select 30
NOTICE:  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)
NOTICE:  Planning time: 0.004 ms
NOTICE:  Execution time: 0.003 ms
DO

Query returned successfully in 127 msec.
```